# MacOS not respecting network device order?

Tags: network, ventura

I got a bit of an issue, in short I connect my MBP to a thunderbolt monitor which has an 1GB Ethernet port built in. When I plug in the monitor, I an 1GBE device shows up in Setting > Network as expected and this works as expected (as confirmed by turning off WIFI on the MPB).

Now, the wrinkle comes when I connect my 10GBE thunderbolt adapter. I've put this as the top priority in the service order list. But, it insists on using the 1GBE connection regardless. I have to physically unplug the ethernet card from the monitor, or disable the 1GBE device in the Network settings , for MacOS to use the 10GBE adapter.

What gives? How can I make MacOS respect the service order?

Comment: I can only guess this is similar to how it handles WiFi transition as you wander between nodes. It will only eventually switch once the first node becomes too weak to sustain. It will otherwise hang onto it even though it can see a far stronger node.

Comment: They are wired though, so from the second you plug in the 10gbe you have a 10x stronger connection. I done some experimentation, and it seems if you have a connection on say, the 1gbe , it will keep and use this connection until you disable it. I’m using a hammerspoon script assigned to a hot key to enable/disable the 1gbe adaptor

Comment: I'm just guessing at the 'logic' - not whether it actually makes sense ;)

Comment: I hear you. The problem is it never seem to change :-( it seems I need to disable the currently active adapter to make it change to another one. I suspect once it negotiated a connection on one adapter it will happily keep using that. The hammerspoon hack works. Just not very impressive I had to do it haha

Comment: Yeah - it's the same for WiFi, they'll hang onto one network node for grim death, even if the other is shiny bright & wall-to-wall.